# Regasm.exe only works in Debug output folder, not install folder

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, installation, regasm

I am writing an add-in dll in c#, VS2012, Win 7 x64. Debugging has been fine; VS registers the dll at the end of building and I've also set up a batch files in my project folder to register and unregister the assembly.

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe" /codebase ".\bin\Debug\MyAddin.dll"
```

This will work every time. FYI my development files are also on a network drive and they will register. Even changing to an absolute file path for the dll works.

Now I am working on deploying the add-in, so I'm starting with WIX to create the installer MSI to put the files in the correct install folder. This is where I start getting the *RA0000 "Unable to locate input assembly 'MyAddin.dll' or one of its dependencies."* error from regasm.exe when I run from a batch file in in my project folder to register the files once they are installed.

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe" /codebase "C:\Program Files\Suite Folder\Product Folder\MyAddin.dll"
```

This never works.  I could see if regasm never worked, but anywhere outside of the output folder won't. So here is what I've tried so far.

- Since my Debug output folder has other files like the .tlb and other stuff I started deleting them one by one all the way down to my add-in and the dependent .dlls. Just to verify what files are really needed to register in the output folder.
- I thought maybe WIX was not creating the files correctly so I copied all the files including the .tlb and others from my output folder into the install folder (I know these should not impact anything but just to be thorough)
- I've unregistered the dll after VS builds thinking that more than one register was the problem.
- Tried running regasm from within the install folder directly so it could find all dependencies there.
- Made sure all of my dlls are x64 platform.
- Tried all lines from batch files in CMD window (w/ and w/o run as admin).
- File attributes from output to install folder are the same.

Any ideas?